# Debugging Javascript in Internet Explorer: display not updating

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

I'm trying to debug an intermittent, possibly timing-related drawing problem with JavaScript in Internet Explorer (IE9 including in IE8 mode).

Using the Developer Tools, I'm stepping through the lines that create, style, and display elements, but the actual browser window remains unchanged (and shows the Windows "Not Responding" title text much of the time), so I can't see what happens when.

With Firefox and Firebug, I can see the main window update at each step. But regrettably this problem doesn't occur in FF, so I can't debug there.

I've web-searched and looked at the MS articles on using the Developer Tools, but I can't find any discussion about single-stepping through JavaScript and seeing the results of each step. Is something wrong on my system, or is this just not possible?

32-bit IE9 on 64-bit Windows 7, in case that's relevant.

Comment: IE just sucks the fun out of web development.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to step through the javascript code but the browser is not refreshing and crashing your best bet to debug it might be to isolate the problem. Say you are doing five things on a certain piece of code. Reduce that to just one thing and gradually pile up different process on top.

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking, but I have run into similar problem with IE 9 before so if you provide some code snippet which can be replicated I could help you further.

**Update**
If you are running into intermittent issues with IE make sure to add a meta tag so that IE doesn't load quirks mode after encountering something on your code. Add the following tag. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

Comment: It's starting to appear that may be my only option.

Comment: And even that isn't much help when the exact same code works sometimes and not others :-(